# 実機でアプリを起動しようとするとCould not launch "" failed to get the task for process とエラーが出てbuildすることができない

Tags: swift, xcode

実機でアプリを起動しようとすると、

```
Could not launch "" failed to get the task for process
```

とエラーが発生してbuildすることができません。

https://ios-docs.dev/process-launch-failed/
上記の記事を参考に、Edit Scheme画面を開き、メニューバーのProduct > Scheme > EditSchemeにおいて
Debug executableのチェックを外したんですが、このままだとbreak pointが止まりません。

なので、本質的な解決を行いたいです。

回答をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: PCの再起動、クリーン(Shift + Command + k)などをしてもダメですか？

Comment: すべて、行いましたが、ダメでした